# Prompting for input in powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, powershell-2.0

I want to the script to prompt for the string pattern in the select-string. How can I do that ?

```
$FileExists = (Test-Path C:\Users\v-hshabb\Desktop\text.txt)
echo $FileExists
If (($FileExists)) 
{
echo $FileExists
  Remove-Item C:\Users\v-hshabb\Desktop\text.txt
}

GET-CHILDITEM  -recurse C:\Enlistment\DAX62\source\*| SELECT-STRING -pattern "@GLS150005"    >text.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Read-Host before calling Get-ChildItem.

```
$pattern = Read-Host
gci -recurse C:\Enlistment\DAX62\source\*| SELECT-STRING -pattern $pattern >text.txt
```